# How can I use the for loop instead of printf statement to execute for a enumerated list as below code?

Tags: c, enumerate

- Using enumerated lists.
- Output on execution of using the printf statement - 6 7 8 2 3 4 6 7 8 1 2 3
- However I wish to use the for loop to execute the enumerated lists instead of the printf statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum Month
{
    January=6, February, March, April=2, May, June, July=6, August, September, October=1, November, December
};

int main()
{
    enum Month m;
    int i;
//  printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December);

    for(m=January; m<=December; m++)
    {
        printf("%d \n ", ?); //what should be the statement ?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I write the for loop such that it executes from jan to december, instead of having to use the
`printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)` statement to print the values?

Comment: It's not possible to iterate over your enum. It starts with `6`, April is `2`, October is `1`, therefore November is `2` and December `3`. You cannot even iterate till `m!=December`, because May has the same value. Do you want to print the numbers? Make an array with the numbers and print them.

Comment: You can't iterate an enum. The members of the enum are just symbolic constants. The statement `for (m=January; m<=December; m++)` is exactly the same as `for (m=6; m<=3; m++)`. Which means the loop won't run at all.

Answer (score 1):

- Here's the corrected answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum Month
{
    January=6, February, March, April=2, May, June, July=6, August, September, October=1, November, December
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    enum Month *month_order[] = { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December };
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", month_order[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Thanks to the above users for giving me insights.
- Usage of pointer to an array, would make it more easy for function calling and storage.
- This also gives perfect output as required.
- The initialization of the month names under enum Month can be changed as per need.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. You can only iterate over the numeric values with `++`. Had your enum values been from say January = 3 to December = 14 in monotonic order without gaps, then - and only then - your approach would have worked.

The only way to do that with arbitrary values order and a loop is that you store the values in that order into an array:

```
enum Month month_order = { January, February, March, April, May, June, July,
                           August, September, October, November, December };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (int)month_order[i]);
    }
```

To avoid repetition you could use the X-macro technique here but it actually wouldn't save keystrokes.